# Ionic React - Redux - IonInput OnIonChange not passing the value to action

Tags: ionic-framework, redux, react-redux

I am trying to use redux for ionic-react application and Not able to capture the input using onIonChange. It works fine with normal useState but when i try to update the state with Redux the value never gets updated to the state

```
 const onInputChangeHandler2 = (event: any, inputIdentifier: string) => {

    props.onAddAttribute({identifier: inputIdentifier, values: event.target.value});
  };
                     <IonItem>
                        <IonLabel position="floating">Attribute Name</IonLabel>
                        <IonInput key="attributeName"
                          onIonChange={(event) =>
                            onInputChangeHandler2(event, "name")
                          }
                          value={attribute.name}
                        />
                      </IonItem>
```

Reducer:

```
const addAttribute = (state, action) => {
            const updatedAttribute = {[action.payload.identifier] : action.payload.values}

            return updateObject(state, updatedAttribute);
    };

const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedObject) => {
    return{
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedObject
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onInputChangeHandler2(event);
```

should the line be

```
onInputChangeHandler2(event, attribute.name);
```

Comment: sorry its a typo...updated the code block with attribute...Also the issue is not with the attribute its with the value that is passed from the input field